# Admin menu link with variable

Tags: custom-post-types, admin, admin-menu, admin-bar

I used this function to display a log out link below the home icon. But how could I put a variable, for instance the current username, on that link to show a profile page?

The function is:

```
    add_action( 'wp_before_admin_bar_render', 'wpdd_admin_bar_edit' );

function wpdd_admin_bar_edit() {
    global $wp_admin_bar;
$wp_admin_bar->add_menu( array(
        'parent' => 'site-name',
        'id' => 'log-out',
        'title' => __( 'Log out' ),
        'href' => 'https://example.com/wp-login.php?action=logout', 
    ));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `wp_get_current_user()` function to retrieve user login data. Also use `get_edit_profile_url()` to get profile page link.

Note: You can use `wp_logout_url()` function for logout url.

Try following code:

```
add_action( 'wp_before_admin_bar_render', 'wpdd_admin_bar_edit' );

function wpdd_admin_bar_edit() {
    global $wp_admin_bar;

    // Show username with profile link 
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    $username = $current_user->user_login;
    $profile_link = get_edit_profile_url();
    $wp_admin_bar->add_menu( array(
        'parent' => 'site-name',
        'id' => 'my_profile',
        'title' => __( 'Profile: ' ) . $username,
        'href' => $profile_link
    ));

    // Logout Link
    $logout_url = wp_logout_url();
    $wp_admin_bar->add_menu( array(
        'parent' => 'site-name',
        'id' => 'log-out',
        'title' => __( 'Log out' ),
        'href' => $logout_url
    ));
}
```

Comment: Cool! Thank you!

Comment: @markseinto . If this answers your question, please consider marking it as the correct answer. It will helps others find it as resolved.